# OpenSSL Certificate (Version 3) with Subject Alternative Name

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509, pki

I'm using the OpenSSL command line tool to generate a self signed certificate. It seems to be working correctly except for two issues. I can't get it to create a `.cer` with a *Subject Alternative Name* (critical) and I haven't been able to figure out how to create a cert that is *Version 3* (not sure if this is critical yet but would prefer learning how to set the version).

Has anyone done this successfully? The default config (`.cfg`) file has seemingly clear documentation (seen below):

> This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
> Import the email address.
> subjectAltName=email:copy

However this does not work. My hunch is that the subject Alternative Name is not showing up b/c it is not present in the V1 specs, which is why I'm also pursuing setting the version.

Here is the config file I'm using:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048 
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem 
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
emailAddress        = myEmail@email.com
req_extensions          = v3_req
x509_extensions         = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
C = [Press Enter to Continue]
C_default = US 
C_min = 2 
C_max = 2 

O = [Press Enter to Continue]
O_default = default 

0.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
0.OU_default = default 
1.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
1.OU_default = PKI 
2.OU=[Press Enter to Continue] 
2.OU_default = ABCD
commonName = Public FQDN of server 
commonName_max = 64

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
subjectAltName         = email:myEmail@email.com
issuerAltName          = issuer:copy
```

Answer (score 41):

Here is the simple steps for you

While generating the CSR you should use `-config` and `-extensions`
and while generating certificate you should use `-extfile` and `-extensions`

Here is the example:

```sh
openssl req -new -nodes -keyout test.key  -out test.csr -days 3650 -subj "/C=US/ST=SCA/L=SCA/O=Oracle/OU=Java/CN=test cert" -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -extensions v3_req
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in test.csr -CA cacert.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out test.pem -extfile /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf  -extensions v3_req
```

hope this helps

Comment: I'm confused: you're generating a CSR (certificate signing request) BEFORE you generate your certificate!? Isn't it supposed to be the other way around?

Comment: @Marc The Certificate Signing Request is needed first. Its name tells you what it is: it's a request to have a new certificate signed by the Certificate Authority (CA). The CA takes that request and signs/generates a brand new certificate for you. You don't make the certificate first and then have it signed.

Comment: it sounds confusing, but this works fine: the SAN-information is added to the Cerfiticate during the signing-process (step 2) and not as you may expect already during CSR-generation.

Answer (score 26):

Alright, none of the other answers on this page worked for me, and I tried every last one of them. What worked for me was a little trick:

when requesting the cert:

```bash
-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$SERVER")) \
-reqexts SAN
```

and when signing the cert:

```bash
-extfile <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$SERVER")) \
-extensions SAN
```

Notice that this is a bash trick, `<(some commands)` makes the stdout output of `some commands` show as a temp file to the outer commands in bash.

So there is no confusion, here is a working script that covers everything from the start, including creating a certificate authority:

```bash
# if the server name is undefined, lets default to 'Some-Server'
SERVER="${SERVER:-Some-Server}"

CORPORATION=My-Corp
GROUP=My-Corporate-Group
CITY=City
STATE=State
COUNTRY=US

CERT_AUTH_PASS=`openssl rand -base64 32`
echo $CERT_AUTH_PASS > cert_auth_password
CERT_AUTH_PASS=`cat cert_auth_password`

# create the certificate authority
openssl \
  req \
  -subj "/CN=$SERVER.ca/OU=$GROUP/O=$CORPORATION/L=$CITY/ST=$STATE/C=$COUNTRY" \
  -new \
  -x509 \
  -passout pass:$CERT_AUTH_PASS \
  -keyout ca-cert.key \
  -out ca-cert.crt \
  -days 36500

# create client private key (used to decrypt the cert we get from the CA)
openssl genrsa -out $SERVER.key

# create the CSR(Certitificate Signing Request)
openssl \
  req \
  -new \
  -nodes \
  -subj "/CN=$SERVER/OU=$GROUP/O=$CORPORATION/L=$CITY/ST=$STATE/C=$COUNTRY" \
  -sha256 \
  -extensions v3_req \
  -reqexts SAN \
  -key $SERVER.key \
  -out $SERVER.csr \
  -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$SERVER")) \
  -days 36500

# sign the certificate with the certificate authority
openssl \
  x509 \
  -req \
  -days 36500 \
  -in $SERVER.csr \
  -CA ca-cert.crt \
  -CAkey ca-cert.key \
  -CAcreateserial \
  -out $SERVER.crt \
  -extfile <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$SERVER")) \
  -extensions SAN \
  -passin pass:$CERT_AUTH_PASS
```

We can then verify that the Subject Alternative name is in the final cert:

```
openssl x509 -in Some-Server.crt -text -noout
```

The pertinent section is:

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:Some-Server
```

So it worked! This is a cert that will be accepted by every major browser (including chrome), so long as you install the certificate authority in the browser. Thats `ca-cert.crt` that you will need to install.

Here is a sample configuration for nginx that would allow you to use the cert:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost:443;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/Some-Server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/Some-Server.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/https-dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice script works everywhere except with android. =( When you try to install the crt Android gives the following error "Private key required to install"

Comment: @Jack Davidson:  Your script appears to have `/bin/bash` style input redirections.  For example: `-config <(cat [snip])`.  You might want to edit your answer to clearly state that it is a `bash` script.  @Michael Hobbs:  The default shell on Android may not be `bash`.

Comment: Above, do not put single quotes in `-config '<(cat ...)'` otherwise the shell will treat it as a literal string. It appears correctly in the script. Unfortunately SO won't let me edit.

Comment: Very nice solution, where the CA password is used just during the keys creations, and then discarded. Much safer, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I just developed a [web based tool](https://kernelmanic.com/certificate-request-generator-with-multiple-common-names-and-subject-alternative-names/) that will generate this command automatically based on form input and display the output.

---

**UPDATE:** see [certificatetools.com](https://certificatetools.com/)

It became so popular that I improved it and published it under its own domain name.

It will not only give you the downloadable .csr, but also provide the openssl commands that were used to generate it, and the needed openssl.cnf configuration options.

**Example:**

OpenSSL Commands

```bash
#generate the RSA private key
openssl genpkey -outform PEM -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out priv.key

#Create the CSR
openssl req -new -nodes -key priv.key -config csrconfig.txt -out cert.csr
```

OpenSSL CSR Config

```
[ req ]
default_md = sha256
prompt = no
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName = example.com
countryName = US
stateOrProvinceName = Louisiana
localityName = Slidell
organizationName = Acme Inc.
[ req_ext ]
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage=critical,serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
IP.0 = 1.1.1.1
IP.1 = 2.2.2.2
DNS.0 = server1.example.com
DNS.1 = server2.example.com
email.0 = email1@example.com
email.1 = email2@example.com
```

Comment: The tool is neat and all but I would really suggest to remove the generation of private keys. If you generate private keys on a server outside of your control (like the one who hosts your tool) the are *by definition* **NOT** private anymore.

Comment: I do not recommend using the keys generated with this tool in production, but I wouldn’t be able to make CSRs or certificates without first generating a private key. The tool is for learning, testing and prototyping. Every operation done on the site returns all OpenSSL commands so everything can be done privately, offline. That is one of the advantages of this tool over others.

Comment: You got more trust in people than I do. If its ready to go someone will use it...

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work with the following version (emailAddress was incorrectly placed):

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048 
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem 
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions          = v3_req
x509_extensions         = v3_ca
  
[req_distinguished_name]
C = [Press Enter to Continue]
C_default = US 
C_min = 2 
C_max = 2 

O = [Press Enter to Continue]
O_default = default 

0.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
0.OU_default = default 
1.OU=[Press Enter to Continue]
1.OU_default = PKI 
2.OU=[Press Enter to Continue] 
2.OU_default = ABCD
commonName = Public FQDN of server 
commonName_max = 64
emailAddress = [Press Enter to Continue] 
emailAddress_default = myEmail@email.com

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
subjectAltName         = email:myEmail@email.com
issuerAltName          = issuer:copy
```

Notes:

- To generate the certificate I used:

  ```
   openssl req -config req.cnf -new -nodes -out req.pem -x509
  ```
- I haven't seen much use for `issuerAltname` (if you have I'd be interested to know where).
- Using `issuer:always` isn't recommended for `authorityKeyIdentifier`.
- Using `email:copy` now works with `subjectAltName`.
- `v3_req` section is superfluous (as well as `req_extensions` line.

Answer (score 4):

What command did you use to make the CSR certificate request? What command did you use to make the certificate file? Different answers for different circumstances you know.

Maybe you are not putting

subjectAltName=email:copy

in the section

[v3_req]

Maybe you are using openssl x509 to generate the certificate, if so you must use

-extfile /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf

because without that it doesnt use your config file

You also might need

-extensions v3_req

command line switch

Answer (score 4):

I referred to several pages, and the most significant helps are from 1. https://geekflare.com/san-ssl-certificate/, 2. https://certificatetools.com/ (see answer from user40662), and 3. answer from Raghu K Nair about the command usage.

Then my successful try:

**san.cnf**

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_req
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = CN                     # C=
stateOrProvinceName    = Shanghai               # ST=
localityName           = Shanghai               # L=
#postalCode             = 200000                 # L/postalcode=
#streetAddress          = "My Address"           # L/street=
organizationName       = My Corporation         # O=
organizationalUnitName = My Department          # OU=
commonName             = myname.mysoftware.mycorporation.com # CN=
emailAddress           = myname@example.com     # CN/emailAddress=
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1   = myname.mysoftware.mycorporation.com
#DNS.2   = other2.com
#DNS.3   = other3.com
```

Command:

```bash
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/C=CN/ST=Shanghai/L=Shanghai/O=My Corporation/OU=My Department/CN=myname.mysoftware.mycorporation.com/emailAddress=myname@example.com" -keyout privateKey.pem -out certificate.crt -config san.cnf -extensions v3_req
```

Answer (score 1):

The `v3_req` is required with the entry `subjectAltName` in the config file. The command

```
openssl x509 ... -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions v3_req
```

will insert the SAN into the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old but just in case it works for anyone on windows, check that the file is UTF-8 encoded, in my case I was getting an error indicating there was an error with the .cnf file, so I opened it on Notepad++ set the file encoding to UTF-8, saved, and ran the openssl command again and it made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#! /bin/dash

#  Steps 1-3 show how to use openssl to create a certificate request
#  that includes Subject Alternative Names.

#  In the uncommon case where you are creating your own CA, steps 4-6
#  show how to use openssl to create a CA and then use that CA to
#  create a certificate from the request.

#  Step 1:  Create an OpenSSL configuration file
#    to specify the Subject Alternative Names

echo  ;  echo  'step  1'
cat  >  foo.cnf  <<EOF
[ req ]
distinguished_name      =  arbitrary_name_1
req_extensions          =  arbitrary_name_2
[ arbitrary_name_1 ]
[ arbitrary_name_2 ]
subjectAltName          =  @arbitrary_name_3
[ arbitrary_name_3 ]
DNS.1                   =  foo.com
DNS.2                   =  bar.com
DNS.3                   =  baz.com
EOF

#  Step 2:  Create a certificate request for foo.com.
#
#  openssl
#    req
#      -config      read openssl configuration from this file
#      -subj        set the commonName of the certificate
#      -newkey      generate a new key (and, by implication, a new request!)
#        -nodes       do not encrypt the new private key ("no DES")
#        -keyout      write the new private key to this file
#      -out         write the request to this file

echo  ;  echo  'step  2'
openssl                         \
  req                           \
    -config    foo.cnf          \
    -subj      '/CN=foo.com'    \
    -newkey    rsa:2048         \
      -nodes                    \
      -keyout  foo.key          \
    -out       foo.req

#  Step 3:  Display the requested extensions.

echo  ;  echo  'step  3'
openssl  req  -in foo.req  -noout  -text  |  \
  grep  -A 2  'Requested Extensions:'

#  Step 4:  Create a certificate authority by creating
#    a private key and self-signed certificate.
#
#  openssl
#    req            generate a certificate request, but don't because ...
#      -x509        generate a self-signed certificate instead
#      -subj        set the commonName of the certificate
#      -days        certificate is valid for N days, starting now
#      -newkey      generate a new private key
#        -nodes       do not encrypt the new private key ("no DES")
#        -keyout      write the new private key to this file
#      -out         write the self-signed certificate to this file

echo  ;  echo  'step  4'
openssl                         \
  req                           \
    -x509                       \
    -subj      "/CN=Custom CA"  \
    -days      4000             \
    -newkey    rsa:2048         \
      -nodes                    \
      -keyout  ca.key           \
    -out       ca.cert

#  Step 5:  Use the certificate authority
#    to create a certificate for foo.com.
#
#  openssl
#    x509             operate on an x509 certificate
#      -req           create an x509 certificate from a request
#      -in            read the request from this file
#      -CA            read the CA certificate from this file
#      -CAkey         read the CA key form this file
#      -extfile       read openssl's configuration from this file
#      -extensions    read extensions from this section of the configuration
#      -days          certificate is valid for N days, starting now
#      -set_serial    set the new certificate's serial number
#      -out           write the new certificate to this file

echo  ;  echo  'step  5'
openssl                                 \
  x509                                  \
    -req                                \
    -in          foo.req                \
    -CA          ca.cert                \
    -CAkey       ca.key                 \
    -extfile     foo.cnf                \
    -extensions  arbitrary_name_2       \
    -days        30                     \
    -set_serial  1001                   \
    -out         foo.cert

#  Step 6:  Display the X509v3 extensions:

echo  ;  echo  'step  6'
openssl  x509  -in foo.cert  -noout  -text  |  \
  grep  -A 2  'X509v3 extensions:'
```

Comment: I tried it, this works, but the CA generated with the `nodes` option (step 4) leaves a security hole opened, I think...

Comment: @Will59 - Whether or not an unencrypted private key is a "security hole" depends (IMO) on your use case and security requirements.  The comment in the script clearly states the consequences of `-nodes`.  If you require an encrypted private key, make adjustments as needed.  If you are creating your own CA, hopefully you have enough background knowledge to understand the choices and related consequences.  My example was intended to be simple and explanatory, and (IMO) `-nodes` is simpler than encrypting the private key.

Answer (score 1):

Though after following the steps described here I started .csr files with:
**X509v3 Subject Alternative Name**
However, my .crt (.pem) files generated with:

```
openssl x509 -req -in domain.csr -extensions SAN -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.crt -days 100
```

still were with:

```
Version: 1 (0x0)
```

and without:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
```

**Solution**

Issue was resolved after I switched to this one:

```
openssl ca -in domain.csr -cert rootCA.pem -keyfile rootCA.key -out domain.crt
```

I started to get domain.crt files with:

```
Version: 3 (0x2)
```

and

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
```

If `openssl ca` complains, you might need to adjust `openssl.cnf` (or `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` for ubuntu, NOTE: if you used brew install openssl - it will be in a different location) file. Just make sure you properly set these:

```
[ CA_default ]
dir= /path/to/rootCA/folder  # Where everything is kept
certificate= $dir/rootCA.pem  # The CA certificate
serial= $dir/rootCA.srl  # The current serial number
private_key= $dir/rootCA.key  # The private key
```

And run:
touch /path/to/index.txt

To generate rootCA.srl you can still use the old command:

```
openssl x509 -req -in domain.csr -extensions SAN -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.crt -days 100
```

More details on `openssl ca` can be found here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ca.html

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24889614/4994931) this slightly different approach worked for me:

1. create a `server.cnf`-file with:

```
nsCertType = server
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate"
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
DNS.1 = localhost
```

2. generate your CSR

```
openssl genrsa -out yourServer_private.key 4096
openssl req -new -key yourServer_private.key -out yourServer.csr
```

3. create your certificate and add SAN-information

```
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in yourServer.csr -CA ../Root/Ca.pem -CAkey ../Root/Ca.key -set_serial 01 -out yourServer.pem -extfile server.cnf
```

4. check your result

```
openssl x509 -in yourServer.pem -text
```

=>

```
(...)
           X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1, DNS:localhost
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption

(...)
```